# How to format JQuery output to top of page and style with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

***Problem 01:***

I have just begun my Jquery/Javascript journey and am having issues moving the output from the script to the top of the page above the link so the toggle does not affect it. If I move the script to the top then it runs before the HTML gets loaded.

***Problem 02:***

Could I also get some tips as to how I can apply CSS to those variables?

Ex: put into a box and change fonts/color etc

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Films</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="mainheading">Films</h1>
  <a href="#" id="actionlink">Add a Film</a>
  <div id="jquerytarget">
    <form>
      <p><label>Film</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="film" id="film"></p>
      <p><label>Rating</label><br />
        <select name="rating" id="rating">
          <option value="1">One Star</option>
          <option value="2">Two Stars</option>
          <option value="3">Three Stars</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p><label>Description</label><br />
        <textarea name="filmdescription" id="filmdescription"></textarea></p>
      <p><button id="submit">Submit</button></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#actionlink").click(function() {
        $("#jquerytarget").slideToggle(200);
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script id="output" type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var film = $("#film").val();
      $("#jquerytarget").prepend("<p>" + film + "</p>")
      var rating = $("#rating").val();
      $("#jquerytarget").prepend("<p>" + rating + "</p>")
      var filmdescription = $("#filmdescription").val();
      $("#jquerytarget").prepend("<p>" + filmdescription + "</p>")
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Answer for problem 01***

If you want to load the HTML first and then run the JavaScript code, you have to wrap your code as follows.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // write your code here
});
```

Your code should be enclosed by the event handler function. An event handler function (or callback) must be registered on the element that emits the event, in our case, the `document` object.

***Answer for problem 02***

You can set CSS properties to the elements as follows. In the following code snippet, I am going to change the background color of the `<p>` elements upon clicking the button.

```html
<p>Paragraph 01</p>
<p>Paragraph 02</p>
<p>Paragraph 03</p>

<button>Change background color of all Paragraphs</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
  });
</script>
```

If you want to assign specific CSS properties to specific classes, you can try the following. The background color of "paragraph 2" can be changed upon clicking the button. I have selected the elements based on theirs 'id's.

```html
<p id="para-01">Paragraph 01</p>
<p id="para-02">Paragraph 02</p>

<button id="addBackgroundChange">Add background color of Paragraph 1</button>
<button id="removeBackgroundChange">Remove background color of Paragraph 1</button>
<button id="toggleBackgroundChange">toggle background color of Paragraph 2</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  // to add a class (the background color)
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addBackgroundChange").click(function() {
      $("#para-01").addClass("new-para-background");
    });
  });

  // to remove a class (the background color)
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#removeBackgroundChange").click(function() {
      $("#para-01").removeClass("new-para-background");
    });
  });

  // to toggle a class (the background color)
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggleBackgroundChange").click(function() {
      $("#para-02").toggleClass("new-para-background");
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
  .new-para-background {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  
</style>
```

Comment: I was able to wrap my code as you have suggested. However I am having trouble selecting the element and applying CSS to it. Since the output data from the script are variables I am having trouble selecting the element to style. Is there a way to style only the variable output from the script?

Comment: In the ***"Answer for problem 02"*** section, I have shown you how to do so. Check the second code snippet in that section. There I have select each HTML element by the IDs assigned, and add CSS classes to them. Remember if you have already applied inline CSS (which is a very bad practice) then, the above code may not work. So, by assigning IDs to each HTML element you want to select, you can style them separately using the code.

Comment: Thank you, I can assign IDs to HTML elements like <p> or body or <h1> however I am unsure how to assign an element to an output from the form. i.e. how do i assign ID to the movie output from the form that results from the below code
var film = $("#film").val();
$("#actionlink").before("<p>" + film + "</p>")

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always wrap your jQuery in the following to have it execute once all of the HTML has been loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // all of your jQuery
}
```

To apply a single CSS attribute, you can use:

`$("#jquerytarget").css("background-color", "red");`

To apply multiple CSS attributes:

`$("#jquerytarget").css({"background-color": "red", "color": "yellow", ...});`

A better way to do this is to write your CSS in your stylesheet and then use `addClass`, `removeClass`, or `toggleClass`:

```
// Adds myClass to the target element
$("$jquerytoggle").addClass("myClass");

// Removes myClass from the target element
$("$jquerytoggle").removeClass("myClass");

// Removes myClass if it is assigned already, or adds it if it doesn't (toggles)
$("$jquerytoggle").toggleClass("myClass");
```